# Class objects not spawning correctly

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

Trying to spawn a circle in OpenGL on the mouse location when you left click but the circles keep spawning at the location of the most recently spawned circle (weird??)
The code (for just spawning a circle at 0.1f, 0.1f which doesn't work):

```
void spawn(int btn, int state, int mX, int mY){
if (btn==GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state==GLUT_DOWN){
    circles.push_back(Ball());
    circles[count].setBallX(0.1f);
    circles[count].setBallY(0.1f);
    circles[count].appear();
    count++;
}
```

and for displaying the circles:

```
void display() {
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
    for(int i = 0; i<count; i++){
    if(circles[i].getSpawn()){
    physics(i);
    glTranslatef(circles[i].getBallX(), circles[i].getBallY(), 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
        glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
        int numSegments = 100;
        GLfloat angle;
        for (int j = 0; j <= numSegments; j++) {
            angle = j * 2.0f * PI / numSegments;
            glVertex2f(cos(angle) * circles[i].getBallRadius(), sin(angle) * circles[i].getBallRadius());
        }
    glEnd();
    }
}   
glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Why have a separate `count`?  Just use `std::vector<>::size()`.

Comment: Do you not have to pre-allocate memory for the vector when you define it at first though?
 E.g.  vector<Ball> circles(100);
Meaning that vector<>::size() wouldn't work?

Comment: Nope, `vector` will take care of that behind the scenes, `size()` will always return the number elements in the vector.  You can [`reserve()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) some space to cut down on allocations in `push_back()`.  You also might be thinking of [`capacity()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity), which might be greater than `size()`.

Answer (score 0):

Move that `glLoadIdentity()` inside your `for`-loop:

```
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    for(int i = 0; i<count; i++)
    {
        glLoadIdentity();

        if(circles[i].getSpawn())
        {
            physics(i);
            glTranslatef(circles[i].getBallX(), circles[i].getBallY(), 0.0f);
            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
            glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
            int numSegments = 100;
            GLfloat angle;
            for (int j = 0; j <= numSegments; j++)
            {
                angle = j * 2.0f * PI / numSegments;
                glVertex2f(cos(angle) * circles[i].getBallRadius(), sin(angle) * circles[i].getBallRadius());
            }
            glEnd();
        }
    }   
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Or push/pop your matrices:

```
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    for(int i = 0; i<count; i++)
    {
        if(circles[i].getSpawn())
        {
            physics(i);
            glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(circles[i].getBallX(), circles[i].getBallY(), 0.0f);
            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
            glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
            int numSegments = 100;
            GLfloat angle;
            for (int j = 0; j <= numSegments; j++)
            {
                angle = j * 2.0f * PI / numSegments;
                glVertex2f(cos(angle) * circles[i].getBallRadius(), sin(angle) * circles[i].getBallRadius());
            }
            glEnd();
            glPopMatrix();
        }
    }   
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Otherwise you're stacking multiple `glTranslate()`s on top of each other which is probably not what you intended.

Comment: thank you so much man, been trying to find what was wrong for nearly a week :)

Comment: @NikolaiSmirnov: If it solved your problem don't forget to upvoate and/or accept the answer.  As we all know Imaginary Internet Points make the world go 'round :)